# React controlled <type='number'> input allows typing in letter?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, input

I am writing an app that contains a controlled input that has the type 'number'. I can still type letters in the input field, but the e.target.value just gets emptied. Does anyone know how I can disable the typing of letters? Namely, if a user types in a letter, the input field will simply not register but still keeps the numbers previously typed in.

Here is my code:

```
export class AddNewRecipe extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={prepField:{numeral:""}};

        this.handleInput = this.handleInput.bind(this)}

   handleInput(e){
      e.preventDefault();   
      if(e.target.className =='prepNumber')
      {   
          console.log(e.target.value)
          const newPrep = Object.assign({}, this.state.prepField)
          newPrep.numeral = currentValue
          this.setState({prepField: newPrep})
      }

render(){
return (<PrepTime 
        handlePrep={this.handleInput}
        prepField={this.state.prepField}
        />
)
}
```

and here is the child component

```
export default function(props){
    
    return(
        <div id = 'prepForm'>
            
                <input id = 'prepFormInput' type='number' className='prepNumber' value={props.prepField.numeral} onChange={props.handlePrep} placeholder='prep time' />
               
        </div>
    )
}
```

Does anyone know why that is? Because if I accidentally type '10v', the e.target.value which I will set to my state 'prepField.numeral' just becomes emptied.

Thank you!

Comment: You're going to need some sort of a REGEX solution.. [Please refer to this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469357/html-text-input-allow-only-numeric-input)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code:

```html
<input id = 'prepFormInput' type='number' className='prepNumber' value={props.prepField.numeral} onChange={props.handlePrep} placeholder='prep time' onkeydown="javascript: return ['Backspace','Delete','ArrowLeft','ArrowRight'].includes(event.code) ? true : !isNaN(Number(event.key)) && event.code!=='Space'" />
```

This will avoids all characters that are not numbers!

This part make's input accept only numbers:

```
!isNaN(Number(event.key))
```

This part make's accept the arrow and delete keys:

```
['Backspace','Delete','ArrowLeft','ArrowRight'].includes(event.code)
```

This part make's Firefox disallow spaces in numbers:

```
event.code!=='Space'
```

Answer (score 0):

(For react Applications)

If someone has text input and wants to accept only whole numbers. You can use the following code.

```js
const numberInputKeyDown = (event: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const eventCode = event.code.toLowerCase();
    if (!(event.code !== null
    && (eventCode.includes("digit")
        || eventCode.includes("arrow")
        || eventCode.includes("home")
        || eventCode.includes("end")
        || eventCode.includes("backspace") 
        || (eventCode.includes("numpad") && eventCode.length === 7)))
    ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    }
};
```

I have compared the length of eventCode to 7 when it includes numpad because its actual value is like numpad0, numpad1 ... numpad9

This function can be specified in onKeyDown such as

```js
<input
    id="myNumberInput"
    type="text"
    placeholder="numeric input"
    onKeyDown={numberInputKeyDown}
/>
```

To extent field to accept decimals or negative numbers you can console.log the `eventCode` in `numberInputKeyDown` to check your required key code and add it in if statement.